# Does anyone know any good resources for learning how to market a web app?

Tags: web-applications, marketing, traffic

I'm a developer first and foremost. **I write web apps but have a hard time generating traffic and converting potential users** once I've released my product into the wild. I know I need to learn more about marketing but I don't know where to start as I've no baseline to judge the quality of the materials I stumble across.

**Does anyone know any websites, blogs, e-books or other resources for learning how to market effectively?**

Comment: It's extremely specific to the purpose of the webapp, if it's so general that you don't know how to find the market, you should probably rethink, and find markets that you can make webapps for instead.

Comment: Try asking on answers.onstartups.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best thing i ever did to help me in marketing via the web was buy "The Social Media Bible" 
[http://www.amazon.com/Social-Media-Bible-Strategies-Business/dp/0470623977/ref=sr_1_5?ie=UTF8&qid=1297662101&sr=8-5](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0470623977)

Here is a great article:
http://web.appstorm.net/roundups/design-roundups/10-marketing-resources-every-app-should-provide/

Here is an old but good article.
http://www.masternewmedia.org/news/2007/12/05/web_application_marketing_strategy_what.htm

These days its all about social marketing. That being said you should also market on Facebook Ads & Google Ads. be sure to track every ad carefully so you know your actually making money & conversions.

Answer (score 0):

Build, market, sell support. You should be aware and prepared for all these from the start, or have a team ready in place.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a developer too. What has worked for me is to tweek your codes and customize it for diverse platforms. Eg. When you build a php script for importing shopping cart details, you may customize it for Magento, OScommerce, OpenCart, etc. and put it on their apps stores. It really works.